# Aumentar tamaño de lista agregando valores

Tags: python

Sé que es algo simple, pero de todas formas tengo problemas para hacerlo.
Quiero agregar valores en una posición específica en una lista, y que vaya aumentando de tamaño a medida que se agregan nuevos.

Ejemplo:

```
lista = [1, 4, 5, 20]
valor=3

#Lista resultante de agregar el valor=3:
lista = [1, 3, 4, 5, 20]
```

Y por ejemplo si quiero cambiar el 3, por el valor 18, sin definir una nueva variable, solo cambiándola desde `valor`, este quede como:

```
valor = 18 # Antes 3

# Lista resultante de agregar el 18, conservando el 3 anteriormente agregado:
lista = [1, 3, 4, 5, 18, 20]
```

Comment: Puedes encontrar descripciones muy claras y ejemplos de uso de los métodos de listas de Python en la documentación en [este enlace](https://docs.python.org/es/3/tutorial/datastructures.html), te recomiendo estudiar ese capítulo de la documentación al completo, es sumamente útil.

Comment: `lista.append(valor)` y en la siguiente línea `lista.sorted()`

Comment: Gracias @alejandroMAD

Comment: Gracias @aeportugal, pero hay alguna forma de hacerlo con ```np.insert```? Cada vez que utilizo esa función y actualizo el valor de ```valor```, como menciono arriba, no se conserva el valor 3 y agrega el valor 18

Answer (score 1):

Partiendo de una lista previamente ordenada, podemos usar el siguiente método:

```
lista = [1, 3, 4, 5, 20]

def agregar( lista, valor ):

       // recorremos la lista
    for i in range( len( lista )):
        if valor < lista[ i ]:

               // si el valor es menor que el contenido en esta posición, 
               // insertamos el nuevo valor
            lista.insert( i, valor )
            return

           //si alcanzamos el final de la lista, agregamos el nuevo valor
        if i == len( lista ) -1:
            lista.append( valor )
        
agregar( lista, 2 )          
print( lista )
```

Answer (score 0):

Las listas en Python, además de ser heterogéneas, pueden contener diferentes tipos de datos (int, float,string, booleanos) y son mutables, es decir, pueden modificarse.

Para reemplazar valores en posiciones específicas, puedes usar la siguiente sintaxis

```
lista = [1, 4, 5, 20]
nuevo_valor = 3
posicion = 2

lista[posicion] = nuevo_valor

print(lista)  


[1, 4, 3, 20]
```

*Recordando* que las posiciones en la lista comienzan en cero.

ex:

```
posicion   valor 
0     =     1 
1     =     4
2     =     5
3     =     20
```

Puedes acceder a una posición específica en una lista en Python utilizando la notación de corchetes.

```
print(lista[0])
```

Una lista en Python tiene el método [**insert**](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists) ( **built-in method** ) que agrega el valor en la posición especificada.

```
nuevo_valor = 3
posicion = 2

lista.insert(posicion, nuevo_valor)
```

El método   sort()  ordena en orden ascendente, sintaxis:

```
lista.sort()

print(lista)
```

Answer (score 0):

Si quieres jugar un poco aquí tienes una opción muy corta:

```
posicion = int(input('Entra la posición...')) #1
valor = int(input('Entra el valor...')) #3
lista = [1, 4, 5, 20]
sublista = lista[:posicion] #sublista = [1]
sublista.append(valor) # sublista =[1, 3]
lista = sublista + lista[posicion:] #lista = [1,3] + [4, 5, 20]
print(lista) #[1, 3, 4, 5, 20]
```